# Kivy 1.8 and Cython 0.21.2

Tags: cython, kivy, buildozer

Using Buildozer I get 12 times:

```
#error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
```

And eventually:

```
Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"
```

According to the [Kivy docs](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html), I use Cython 0.21.2.

[See the full log](http://pastebin.com/mDv7F804).

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have Kivy 1.8.0 installed, and you're building Kivy 1.9.0 with buildozer. You will need to uninstall or upgrade your system Kivy. This is a bug in Cython, because it is using the system-installed `pxd`s before the local directory `pxd`s.

Comment: I ended up installing my Linux Mint all over again. Never uninstall Python from Linux Mint.